# The attempt to connect to the report server failed - Setting URL and Path in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I'm trying to connect to a `Report` (rdlc file) using ASP.NET Web Applications. I'm working with VS2010 and the `Report Server` is version 2008.

I have the following URL to the report which works fine:

```
http://server url/Products/_layouts/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/Products/Dashboards/Product_tool.rdl&Source=Server Url/Products/Dashboards/Forms/AllItems.aspx&DefaultItemOpen=1
```

When i enter that URL in my browser it first asks for a username password. When i log in then the `Report` shows up just fine.

Now i need to display this report in a `Report Viewer`. So i added a `Report Viewer` control to my `aspx` page. I configured the URls for it like so:

`Report Server:** http://server url/Products/_layouts/ReportServer`

`Report Path:** /Products/Dashboards/Product_tool.rdl`

I'm not really sure if that is even correct..?

In any case, in my `PageLoad` i have the following line of code:

```
eportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportCredentials("myuser", "mypass");
```

The `ReposrtCredentials` class is taken from: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/c65abca7-0fdb-40fb-aabe-718f63377a55/ (from Phil)

Now when i run my Web Application i get the following error:

> The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your
>   connection information and that the report server is a compatible
>   version.

Now i'm not sure if the URL i supplied to the `Report Viewer` is right? Or what the problem else could be.

Anyone any idea..?

Comment: path to a report is always reportserver+ reportpath, hence in your case it seems to be http://server url/Products/_Layouts/ReportServer/Products/Dashboards/Product_tool.rdl...&DefaultItemOpen=1.. verify if this url is correct. Typically, a report url generally has reportserver url + directory + report name i.e. http://server url/Products/_layouts/ReportServer/Products/Dashboards/ReportName

Comment: @ManishMishra When i goto: `http://server/ReportServer` it then displays an **Index** (is that what its called?). So i cab basically browse through directories using my web browser. When i use this URL: `http://server/ReportServer/Products/Dashboards/Product_tool.rdl` then it still shows me the same page. Is that a sign that the `rdl` must be located at a different path?

Comment: see @w00, you might b facing an authentication issue, when you want to display SSRS reports in asp.net web application, you should consider implementing IReportServerConnection2 interface; wait  for my solution, to how to use this interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure your report viewer,check **whether the account you use has permission to view the report** because it is necessary that you have access when using server report.
Check out this link too. They will be of help : http://forums.asp.net/t/1562624.aspx/1

Comment: Thanks, the import part for me in there was that i needed to use the full URL to my RDL file.

Answer (score 4):

In order to Integrate SSRS Reports into an ASP.NET application, follow these steps.

Firstly, Implement IReportServerConnection2 interface. I did something like this:

```
  public sealed class CustomReportServerConnection : IReportServerConnection2
    {
        public WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
        {
            get
            {
                // Use the default Windows user.  Credentials will be
                // provided by the NetworkCredentials property.
                return null;
            }
        }
        public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
        {
            get
            {
                // Read the user information from the web.config file.  
                // By reading the information on demand instead of 
                // storing it, the credentials will not be stored in 
                // session, reducing the vulnerable surface area to the
                // web.config file, which can be secured with an ACL.

                // User name
                string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Utility.Constants.AppConst.REPORT_USER].ToString(); 

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                    throw new Exception(Utility.Constants.AppConst.MESSAGE_MISSING_USER_NAME);

                // Password
                string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Utility.Constants.AppConst.REPORT_PASSWORD].ToString();

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                    throw new Exception(Utility.Constants.AppConst.MESSAGE_MISSING_PWD);

                // Domain
                string domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Utility.Constants.AppConst.REPORTS_DOMAIN].ToString();

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
                    throw new Exception(Utility.Constants.AppConst.MESSAGE_MISSING_DOMAIN);

                return new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
            }
        }
        public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string userName, out string password, out string authority)
        {
            authCookie = null;
            userName = null;
            password = null;
            authority = null;
            // Not using form credentials
            return false;
        }
        public Uri ReportServerUrl
        {
            get
            {
                string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Utility.Constants.AppConst.REPORT_SERVER_URL].ToString();

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
                    throw new Exception(Utility.Constants.AppConst.MESSAGE_MISSING_URL);

                return new Uri(url);
            }
        }
        public int Timeout
        {
            get
            {
                return int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Utility.Constants.AppConst.REPORT_SERVER_TIME_OUT].ToString());
                // return 60000; // 60 seconds
            }
        }
        public IEnumerable<Cookie> Cookies
        {
            get
            {
                // No custom cookies
                return null;
            }
        }
        public IEnumerable<string> Headers
        {
            get
            {
                // No custom headers
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now in your Configuration AppSettings place following keys ( or provide these values from wherever you want):

```
    <add key="ReportServerUrl" value="http://sqlServerURL/ReportServer_SQL2008R2"/>

    <!--Development TargetReportFolder-->
    <add key="TargetReportFolder" value="/AppReporting/"/>
    <add key="ReportServerTimeOut" value="600000"/>
    <add key="ReportViewerServerConnection" value="FullyQualified Name of ur CustomReportServerConnection,ProjectName"/>
    <add key="ReportsUser" value="ReportUser"/>
    <add key="ReportsPassword" value="reportPassword"/>
    <add key="ReportsDomain" value="myDomain"/>
```

Now , in your .aspx page, drag a reportViewer something like this:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="RptViewer" runat="server" AsyncRendering="False" SizeToReportContent="true"
            ProcessingMode="Remote" Width="100%" BackColor="#F7F8F9" OnReportError="RptViewer_ReportError"
            OnReportRefresh="RptViewer_ReportRefresh1" Height="">
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

and configure your ReportViewer in the codeBehind..
place your `ReportParameter` properly.

it shud give you an idea...

point is, you need to authenticate properly, hence writing your custom ReportServerConnection

Comment: Thanks, authentication wasn't really the problem though. I got this error because the **Report Path** was wrong. I found the correct URLs and its working now. I'm using the full URL to the rdl file.

Comment: Thanks w00, very helpful comment, it finally put me on the right track.

Comment: @w00 - How do you find the correct report path? I'm currently using this: http://mardom-sql-srv01/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fScorePorYears