# simultaneous requests time out from same browser

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

I have weird situation: if I launch very slow report from IE and subsequently from another tab make more requests to the database through asp.net application - they time out as if report locked the entire db. Now if I launch report through firefox - it still is slow, but requests made through IE are fine. Same story if browsers are swapped - as if I can't launch report and use my app from the same browser. I use windows auth, sql server express, reporting services. Any clues to this weirdness would be appreciated.

**Edit**
Reports are handled from the same IIS app as main application's, it's just some Report.aspx page.
Also I've checked through profiler - no new requests to db arrive as long as report's request is active. Everything is on the same server

**Edit1**

> Concurrent Requests and Session State
>
> Access to ASP.NET session state is exclusive per session, which means
>   that if two different users make concurrent requests, access to each
>   separate session is granted concurrently. However, if two concurrent
>   requests are made for the same session (by using the same SessionID
>   value), the first request gets exclusive access to the session
>   information. The second request executes only after the first request
>   is finished. (The second session can also get access if the exclusive
>   lock on the information is freed because the first request exceeds the
>   lock time-out.) If the EnableSessionState value in the @ Page
>   directive is set to ReadOnly, a request for the read-only session
>   information does not result in an exclusive lock on the session data.
>   However, read-only requests for session data might still have to wait
>   for a lock set by a read-write request for session data to clear.

**Edit2**
Solved the problem by adding this to web.config

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ReportViewerServerConnection" value="AS.Web.Providers.ReportServerConnection, AS.Web.Common" />

<add key="MyReportServerUrl" value="http://reportserver/reportserver" />
<add key="MyReportViewerUser" value="user" />
<add key="MyReportViewerPassword" value="password" />
<add key="MyReportViewerDomain" value="domain" />-->
</appSettings>
```

Where user should be added in ssrs security settings (I've used my windows login).
And ReportServerConnection is in separate library AS.Web.Common:

```
public sealed class ReportServerConnection : IReportServerConnection2
{
    public WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
    {
        get
        {
            // Use the default Windows user.  Credentials will be
            // provided by the NetworkCredentials property.
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
    {
        get
        {
            // Read the user information from the web.config file.  
            // By reading the information on demand instead of 
            // storing it, the credentials will not be stored in 
            // session, reducing the vulnerable surface area to the
            // web.config file, which can be secured with an ACL.

            // User name
            string userName =
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
                    ["MyReportViewerUser"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                throw new Exception(
                    "Missing user name from Web.config file");

            // Password
            string password =
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
                    ["MyReportViewerPassword"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                throw new Exception(
                    "Missing password from Web.config file");

            // Domain
            string domain =
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
                    ["MyReportViewerDomain"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
                throw new Exception(
                    "Missing domain from Web.config file");

            return new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
        }
    }

    public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie,
                out string userName, out string password,
                out string authority)
    {
        authCookie = null;
        userName = null;
        password = null;
        authority = null;

        // Not using form credentials
        return false;
    }

    public Uri ReportServerUrl
    {
        get
        {
            string url =
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[
                    "MyReportServerUrl"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
                throw new Exception(
                    "Missing url from the Web.config file");

            return new Uri(url);
        }
    }

    public int Timeout
    {
        get
        {
            return 60000; // 60 seconds
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Cookie> Cookies
    {
        get
        {
            // No custom cookies
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Headers
    {
        get
        {
            // No custom headers
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Similar post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985689/reportviewer-is-blocking-other-functionalites-until-the-loading-of-report-viewer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could be running into a session state issue:
http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2006/05/21/session-state-uses-a-reader-writer-lock.aspx

you are not running into the issue when using two different browsers because they are running with two different session cookies.